# Python3 scapy pfcp - iterating over IE_List

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I'm trying to iterate over scapy.contrib.pfcp.PFCPSessionEstablishmentResponse with scapy. As far as I know this is a IE_list
[(https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.contrib.pfcp.html#scapy.contrib.pfcp.PFCPSessionEstablishmentResponse)](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.contrib.pfcp.html#scapy.contrib.pfcp.PFCPSessionEstablishmentResponse)

I was trying to iterate over IE_list but i'm getting as a response "IE_List":

```
for a in s[pfcp.PFCPSessionEstablishmentResponse].fields:
        print(a.title())
```

Does anyone have any idea how to use it to itereate over item names ?
Showing scapy packet it looks as shown below:

(...)
###[ PFCP Session Establishment Response ]###
\IE_list   
|###[ IE Node ID ]###
|  ietype    = Node ID
|  length    = 5
|  spare     = 0x0
|  id_type   = IPv4
|  ipv4      = 127.0.0.7
|  extra_data= ''
|###[ IE Cause ]###
|  ietype    = Cause
|  length    = 1
|  cause     = Request accepted
|###[ IE F-SEID ]###
|  ietype    = F-SEID
|  length    = 13
|  spare     = 0x0
|  v4        = 1
|  v6        = 0
|  seid      = 0x6
|  ipv4      = 127.0.0.7
|  extra_data= ''
|###[ IE Created PDR ]###
(...)